# Implementing an "Email this" button?

Tags: plugins, email

We've inherited a customer with a good looking Wordpress site but the previous agency didn't fully implement the "Email This" feature. I mean, their theme has a link for "Email this" on every page but there's nothing underneath it.

We've been instructed to make it work.

So, the ideal would be for a solution which retains the existing button (which has been styled quite nicely), but just supplies the plumbing work underneath.

AFter a quick search for a plug in which will implement this, I found:

- email2friend
- WP-Email

But it's not clear whether these will add their "own" button to the article (which will presumably not look as nice as the existing themed button) Can we plumb it into our existing button? Also, in each case, can we tweak the mini form it throws up to make it match our theme?

Finally, if there's a plug in that's better than either of these two, please advise.

### **Update**:

Went with **WP-Email** in the end which was fully featured and easy to configure and as **mireille raad** said, it was easy enough to tweak the CSS and images to make the button fit our site 100%. The form that came with it immediately picked up the colour scheme and fonts used in our theme, without us having to do anything at all.

Comment: Have you considered something a bit more modern like Share buttons? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/

Comment: @t31os yes that's an option but the site is deliberately conservative. ok even conservative folk know of facebook and twitter but if the plugin comes loaded with a dozen other obscure icons no one has ever heard of (except for techies & teens) then personally i think that looks pretty crap. i think the customer is going to agree. he just wants basic email, print, and arguably facebook.

Comment: RE: deliberately conservative - I can understand that, no problem.   RE: The question - If the button currently do does not do anything where does the mini-form you mentioned come from? Any chance you could post the code you have in place currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well wouldn't it be easier to get any plugin working - then go into plugin folder/code and search for the image it uses and replace it with the nice image/themed one ?

Comment: I'm not used to editing plugins. i'm not sure how sealed the average plugin is. if it's as accessible as you say then yes, that would seem to be the solution.

Comment: Creating/editing a plugin is a snap. To see how easy it is, take a look at the "Hello Dolly" plugin (`wp-content/plugins/hello.php` in the standard distribution): a comment, some code, and a filter/hook or two and Bob's Your Uncle! :-)

Comment: This should be relatively easy. However, that solution could break if the plugin is updated.

Answer (score 2):

This code is designed to allow readers to click on the button and have it open up their default email software and create a subject and link that point to the post the reader is currently visiting.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
function isPPC() {
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("PPC") != -1) return true;
else return false;
}
if(isPPC()) {
document.write('<a class="contact" HREF=\"mailto:\?subject\=Take a look at this page I found, ' + document.title + '?body=You can see this page at: ' + window.location + '\" onMouseOver="window.status=\'Send your friends e-mail about this page\'; return true" TITLE="Send your friends e-mail about this page">Email to a Friend<\/a>');
}
else { document.write('<a class="contact" HREF=\"mailto:\?body\=Take a look at this page I found titled ' + document.title + '. You can see this page at: ' + window.location + '\" onMouseOver="window.status=\'Send your friends e-mail about this page\'; return true" TITLE="Send your friends e-mail about this page" rel="nofollow">Email This!<\/a>');
}
// End -->
</script>
```

Found it here : http://wphacks.com/how-to-add-email-this-button-wordpress-blog/